Subclassing random.Random produces different results with same seed
I've run into something I don't understand. This code:
import random


class MyRandom(random.Random):
    pass


r = random.Random()
r.seed(10)
print(r.randint(0, 20))
print(r.randint(0, 20))
print(r.randint(0, 20))

print("------------")

r2 = MyRandom()
r2.seed(10)
print(r2.randint(0, 20))
print(r2.randint(0, 20))
print(r2.randint(0, 20))


...prints:
18
1
13
------------
18
1
13

This is as expected, since it's the same seed. But if I innocuously override the random() method like this:
import random



class MyRandom(random.Random):

    def random(self):
        return super().random()



r = random.Random()
r.seed(10)
print(r.randint(0, 20))
print(r.randint(0, 20))
print(r.randint(0, 20))

print("------------")
r2 = MyRandom()
r2.seed(10)
print(r2.randint(0, 20))
print(r2.randint(0, 20))
print(r2.randint(0, 20))

Suddenly it prints:
18
1
13
------------
20
9
6

Why on earth would that change anything? How is the call to super somehow upsetting the internal state?
Even weirder, there isn't a discrepancy if I'm calling r.random() instead of r.randint(). Perhaps that clue will be helpful.

Have you looked at the code in random.py?  The source code is all installed on your computer.  Check __init_subclass.   When random is defined in a subclass, it uses a slightly different path to generate the random values.

Interesting! That's exactly where the discrepancy is coming from! Do you have any idea why it works like this? It seems like randint uses _randbelow, which is based on getrandbits if it's not a subclass and random if it is. Do you think it's because one of the main reasons to subclass random is to override the random function itself, and so if you've done that, then they want to base other methods on that?

I think that's exactly it.  If you override random, then that's what you want to use.  If not, then it uses its default method.
